# how to fix this error : zipalign: symbol lookup error: zipalign: undefined symbol: _zn11zip_archive7inflateerkns_6readerejjpns_6writerepm

Tags: reverse-engineering, apktool, zipalign

When i run the zip command into my linux machine it can not work and give me the error message above

I un apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, remove the libbacktrack.so.0 file and replace it with a new one but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Solved following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GpqZKKRdZs
Install zipalign from ubuntu rep instead of from kali rep.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).